# Клавиатура вместо знака деления и части других символов начала писать вещи вроде àÀàÉè

Tags: клавиатура

Клавиатура вместо знака деления и части других символов начала писать странные символы àÀàÉèÉÈèé. Всё что я нашёл в интернете на этот счёт было с тем что это альт символы, но альт я не нажимал. Клавиатура razer, кто-то сталкивался с подобным? И как это исправить?

Comment: Ох уж эта клавиатура!

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что не по теме.

Answer (score 1):

Дело было в том, что у меня слетела раскладка и вместо Английского США она была Канадской международной.